# Wordpress 3.1: Videoplayer implemented?

Tags: videos, flash

when using "insert video" from the post-editor - i'm only getting a normal hyperlink to the video - is it possible to display a flash-videoplayer instead?
is there a default videoplayer in wordpress or will i need a plugin?
in that case - which plugin is recommended?

thx

Comment: Have you tried any of the video plugins found by googling: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wordpress+video+player+plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the "Insert video" action does not do much beyond creating a link. WordPress does not contain a generic player that can play any video hosted anywhere on the internet, but it does support something better: [embedding via oEmbed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds). This means you can put the URL of the video page in your content, and it will replace it with the proper embed code - if the video site supports oEmbed (most popular sites do), and if WordPress is configured to allow embed from this site (but you can enable oEmbed autodiscovery or use a plugin like [Embedly](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/embedly/) to add more sites).

The support in the editor could be better, but this is probably the most future-proof way to embed videos in your posts.