# Retrieving all Links from a Post?

Tags: links, regex

i'm using the default "insert video" function from wordpress (which inserts a normal hyperlink to the video only) and would like to replace that link with something else like a video player.

my question:
what's the regex pattern for grabbing all links inside a post?
thx

Comment: Why not just add this into the other question? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/wordpress-3-1-videoplayer-implemented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer your question below, but have you looked at using embeds? Look here for more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds

The simplest regex for this would look something like `http\:\/\/.*\b`

Here's an example of it in action:

```php
<?php 

$file = 'test.txt';

$fp = fopen($file, 'r');

$contents = fread($fp, filesize($file));

$matches = array();

preg_match_all('/http\:\/\/.*\b/', $contents, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

Where the file I reference looks like this:

```
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12809/retrieving-all-links-from-a-post

http://www.youtube.com/

http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
```

and the return looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12809/retrieving-all-links-from-a-post
            [1] => http://www.youtube.com
            [2] => http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
        )

)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why my code is red here. It syntax highlighted correctly in the edit view.

Comment: @Lea Cohen: Thanks! Sadly, that didn't solve it :(

Comment: The `[regex]` tag for the question forced regex-style syntax highlighting on the answers too, instead of the default style which works for PHP. You can now [give a language hint](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify), and I edited your question to do it (partly because this was the first time I could try this, and I was curious).